# Is it possible to use local filepaths in CSS's url()?

Tags: css

I want to write a user (i.e. local to my machine) CSS rule for an external website to add a file *local* to my machine as background, i.e. *not* from a webserver. Site https://example.org, which has one `h1` tag and two `p` tags is used as an example.

I tried the following:

```
p {
    background: url('/home/andrybak/1.png') repeat;
}
h1 {
    background: url('file:///home/andrybak/1.png') repeat;
}
```

Both options do not work in Firefox and in Chrome. Does CSS's `url()` support [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)?

Comment: @NagaSaiA thank you!

Answer (score 1):

CSS's `url()` only supports URLs, not necessarily URIs. The `file://` URI scheme defines a URI, not a URL. The main difference is that while a URI only identifies a resource, a URL specifies the *location* of a resource on the internet.

Source: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#urls